# Is there a way to convert names to initials?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a name field that I want to show up as just initials in the report.

So

```
John Smith
Baba Booey
Jane Doe
```

Would show up as:

```
JS
BB
JD
```

Is there a formula I can run to just show the names?

Comment: Are these different names or its a single name `John Smith Baba Booey Jane Doe`

Comment: different names "John Smith" "Baba Booey" "Jane Doe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Just Create a Formula

Try This code

```
StringVar name_first;
StringVar name_last;
name_first := left({Field_name},1);
name_last := MID({Field_name}, INSTR({Field_name}, " ")); 
name_first+left(name_last,2);
```

Hope, This will give you desired results

Answer (score 0):

The ProperCase() function will convert the first letter of each word to uppercase and the rest to lowercase. You can then loop through the converted name and append every capital letter to the result. This should work for any number of first/middle/surnames, and whether the first letter is already capitalized or not:

```
Local stringVar FullName := ProperCase({FullName_Field});
Local stringVar ResultString := "";
Local numberVar x;
Local stringVar c;
for x := 1 to Length(FullName)
do (
    c := mid((FullName), x, 1);
    if ascw(c) >= 65 and ascw(c) <= 90 then ResultString := ResultString + c;
);
ResultString;
```